# Доступ к элементам двумерного массива через индексы

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется код:

```
int isShipShooted(char field[24][24], int sh_v, int sh_h) {

    //Увеличиваем индексы в 2 раза, т.к поле не 10х10, а 20х20 (24х24, но первые и последние 2 символа - границы)
    sh_v *= 2;
    sh_h *= 2;

    //Проверяем, не занята ли ячейка (не находится ли там уже корабль)
    if (field[sh_h][sh_v] == '#') {
        cout << "Damaged!" << endl;
        //Изменяем с:
        //##
        //##
        //на
        //**
        //**
        field[sh_h][sh_v] = '*';
        field[sh_h][sh_v+1] = '*';
        field[sh_h+1][sh_v] = '*';
        field[sh_h+1][sh_v+1] = '*';
    }
    //В противном случае заменяем ячейки на:
    //00
    //00
    else {
        cout << "Miss"<<endl;
        field[sh_h][sh_v] = '0';
        field[sh_h][sh_v + 1] = '0';
        field[sh_h + 1][sh_v] = '0';
        field[sh_h + 1][sh_v + 1] = '0';
    }
    return 0;
}
void main(){
        cout << "Enter the line: ";
        cin >> sh_v;
        cout << "Enter the column: ";
        cin >> sh_v;
        isShipShooted(field, sh_v, sh_h);
        showField(field, i, j, n);
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать некое подобие игры Морской Бой.
Задача данной части кода - проверять, не занята ли ячейка символом '#' (не находится ли там палуба корабля) и изменять значение данных ячеек (поле увеличено в 2 раза, как и корабли => палуба 2х2) либо на '*', либо на '0'. Однако при любом вводе упорно заменяет элементы правильного столбца, но нулевой строки. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
    cin >> sh_v;
    cout << "Enter the column: ";
    cin >> sh_v;
```

Т.е. вы оба раза вводите данные в `sh_v`, а `sh_h` оставляете нулевым (похоже, это глобальная переменная)? :)

Вы отладчиком не пробовали воспользоваться? или хоть отладочным выводом?...